# Cannot see my SD card in parted

Tags: sd-card, parted

When I plug in my card reader, it shows up at `/def/sdf`, and when I insert this SD card I also see `/dev/sdf1`, but `parted` won't show the disk. It doesn't have any information I need, I just want to use the card. Why doesn't it show up in `parted`?

EDIT (more details):

- I'm on Ubuntu 14.04
- `sudo parted -l` will not list my SD card
- After plugging the SD reader:
  `$ ls /dev/sd*
  /dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda5  /dev/sdb  /dev/sdc  /dev/sdd  /dev/sde  /dev/sdf  /dev/sdf1

  $ sudo file -s /dev/sdf
  /dev/sdf: writable, no read permission

  $ sudo fdisk /dev/sdf
  fdisk: unable to open /dev/sdf: No medium found`

Comment: What does `parted` actually say? What about `fdisk /dev/sdf`?

Comment: What does (as root) `file -s /dev/sdf1` give you?  Add the output to your question.

Comment: Always include your operating system.

Comment: @DisplayName - Isn't Linux/Unix implied from the web site :-) Well, I've Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Um, Yes, but Linux and Unix isn't the same thing, a solution to your problem depends on which Unix/Linux you use. FreeBSD, BSD, OS X, Linux etc.

Comment: It looks like `/dev/sdf` has the wrong permissions. I don't know why that would happen. Did you do any kind of manual configuration? What is the output of `ls -l /dev/sdf` and of `grep sdf /etc/udev/rules.d/*`?

Comment: check into gparted application, May be card file system corrupt. Jaymin D

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem until I specified the device after the `gparted` command on the command line; e.g. `gparted /dev/mmcblk1` where `mmcblk1` is the SD card in my SD card reader. This opened the gparted gui with the specified device listed and from there I was able to create new partition, etc.